# SQLAlchemy (w/ Postgres) - How to limit full-text search to one column of many indexed?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

I have a (postgres) TSVECTOR column defined in a model as follows:

```
def Model(Base):

#... Column Definitions (overview, funding, and other text columns) ..
funding = Column(Text)
overview = Column(Text)
etc..
index_tsvector = Column(TSVECTOR)
__table_args__ = (Index('cb_wikis_index', 'index_tsvector',postgresql_using='gin'), )
```

and the trigger that defines what would be indexed as follows (showing SQL trigger definition):

```
CREATE TRIGGER index_tsvector_update
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON "CrunchBase_startup_wikis"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('index_tsvector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'competitors', 'funding', 'investments', 'overview');
```

So this works and is VERY fast (as compared to the LIKE search). However, I would like to limit in *which column* of the multiple columns indexed by index_tsvector a match would be found.

My search query is:

```
search_string = 'Cats & Dogs'
qry = session.query(Model).filter(Model.index_tsvector.op('@@')(func.to_tsquery(search_string))).all()
```

I can't see where to limit the search to a certain column (e.g., 'overview' only).
Is there a way to instruct SQLAlchemy to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might be too late, but you can modify the update trigger by specifying the overview column only:

```
CREATE TRIGGER index_tsvector_update
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON "CrunchBase_startup_wikis"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('index_tsvector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'overview');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the weights feature for this.

```
setweight( to_tsvector(columnA), 'A') || setweight( to_tsvector(columnB), 'B') ...
```

in your query:

```
'someValue:B'::tsquery
```

Will search only column B.

More here: https://database-patterns.blogspot.com/2014/07/postgresql-text-search-multiple-columns.html

Comment: Link seems dead :(

Comment: @Steffo fixed it